# Bypass required attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

In class I have this :

```
public class CustomerMvc 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName mandatory.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Email not valid.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

In another class, I have this :

```
public class CartMvc
{
    public CustomerMvc Customer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "VAT mandatory.")]
    public int VatId { get; set; }
}
```

A `Save` method int the controller, receive a model type `CartMvc`. The problem is, in this case, I don't want validate the property type `CustomerMvc` but only `VatId`.

Is there a way to bypass, in this case, the validation on `CustomerMvc` ? Other way ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class SaveCustomerMvcViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SaveCartMvcViewModel
{
    public SaveCustomerMvcViewModel Customer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "VAT mandatory.")]
    public int VatId { get; set; }
}
```

Now of course your Save controller action will take the appropriate view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SaveCartMvcViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

And as a side remark, putting the `[Required]` attribute on a non-nullable integer property (your `VatId` property) hardly makes any sense because a non-nullable integer will always have a value. If you want to validate that the user actually entered some value you'd better use a nullable integer on your view model:

```
public class SaveCartMvcViewModel
{
    public SaveCustomerMvcViewModel Customer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "VAT mandatory.")]
    public int? VatId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course but it's another class. I wanted to avoid duplicate class. In this case the customer doesn't need to be validated. But if no other way ok :)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, it has a different purpose. it is called View model, whereas other classs is domain model.

Comment: What do you mean it's in another class? Best practices in ASP.NET MVC dictate that you should have view model for each view. As you can see you have different validation logic between the different actions. So you should have different view models for them. And to ease the mapping between your view models and your domain models I would recommend you AutoMapper.